# Find and add quotes in between particular string

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, csv

when I'm working with csv, unwanted commas(',') is misleading my csv file, in result it gives the inconsistency.

please find in details below.

My sample csv file:

```
1|a,b|4
1|c,d|4
1|e,f|4
1|g,h|4
1|i,j|4
```

I want the end result As:

```
1|"a,b"|4
1|"c,d"|4
1|"e,f"|4
1|"g,h"|4
1|"i,j"|4
```

**After adding the quotes I will replace "|" with "," so that my csv will work as I expected.**

I used below commnd but its not giving as exprected.

```
sed -e 's/,/"&"/' file1.txt
```

Comment: But your file is not comma-separated ! Given what you want to quote, it is bar (pipe, "|") separated. If you quote it as shown, it makes invalid CSV (because quotes in fields need to be quoted). If your problem is importing it, any decent package will allow "|" as an alternative separator.

Comment: Hi @Paul_Pedant sorry for misleading you and everyone after i add quotes i will replace "|"   with "," so that my csv will work perfectly.

Comment: I think you are suffering from an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Kusalananda's answer solves your actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS=","; dq="\042"}
{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /,/)$i = dq $i dq;}1' file
```

First of all,  field separator(`FS`) and output field separator(`OFS`) are set to `|`  and `,` respectively. A new variable `dq` is set to double quotes(`\042`) in `BEGIN` rule.

If comma is found in main block, then that field is changed with double quotes around the field.

If you want to put quotes around everything but numbers, then the following would do.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS=","; dq="\042"}
{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i+0 != $i)$i = dq $i dq;}1' file
```

Comment: Hey @Prabhjot Singh Thank you so much it is working fine

Comment: @G.kalyan I am glad to hear this.

Comment: About `gsub(/^.*$/, dq $i dq, $i)`: a) you should be using `sub()` here instead of `gsub()` because you can't do multiple substitutions using a regexp that matches the whole field so using `gsub()` is misleading at best and may also be inefficient. b) you shouldn't be using any `*sub()` function at all because it's not necessary to do more than a simple string assignment and having `$i` in the replacement text means it'll fail when `$i` contains a replacement metachar such as `&`. All you need here is a simple `$i = dq $i dq`. Always be wary of using input data in a regexp or replacement text

Comment: Please elaborate `Always be wary of using input data in a regexp or replacement text`.

Answer (score 14):

Using `csvformat` from [`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and assuming that the end result should be a CSV file with comma as delimiter (as described in the text of the question):

```
$ csvformat -d '|' file
1,"a,b",4
1,"c,d",4
1,"e,f",4
1,"g,h",4
1,"i,j",4
```

This reformats the CSV file from having `|`-characters as delimiter to having the default comma as delimiter.  In doing so, it properly quotes the fields that need quoting.

This also properly handles fields with embedded newlines:

```
$ cat file
1|a,b|4
1|c,d|4
1|e,f|4
1|g,h|4
1|i,j|4
2|"line 1,
line2"|5
```

```
$ csvformat -d '|' file
1,"a,b",4
1,"c,d",4
1,"e,f",4
1,"g,h",4
1,"i,j",4
2,"line 1,
line2",5
```

If you have a document in some structured document format, such as CSV, JSON, XML, YAML, TOML, etc.,  there is no reason *not* to use a parser for that document format to parse that document.

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
awk -F'[|]' -v OFS=',' -v q='"' '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i=q $i q }1' infile
```

with `-F'[|]'` we defined input field separator.
with `-v OFS=','` we defined output filed separator.
`NF` identifies how many fields are there in each line/record based on the FS (input field separator), so we loop over the number of fields and add double quotes for each of them and print the final update on the line with [awk's `1` idiom](/q/63891/72456) for the print.

note that all the fields are getting quoted with this command which obviously that is not an issue for having a valid CSV file.

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`:

```bsh
$ sed 's/[^|]*,[^|]*/"&"/g; y/|/,/' ip.txt
1,"a,b",4
1,"c,d",4
1,"e,f",4
1,"g,h",4
1,"i,j",4
```

- `s/[^|]*,[^|]*/"&"/g` add double quotes to all fields containing `,`
- `y/|/,/` change all `|` characters to `,`

With `perl`:

```bsh
perl -F'\|' -lane 'print join ",", map {/,/ ? qq("$_") : $_} @F'
```

This uses `|` as input field separator. Then `map` will add double quotes for all fields containing `,`. Finally, `join` is used to combine the fields with `,` character.

Answer (score 0):

Another `sed` way:

```
  sed 's;\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)|\(.*\)$;\1,"\2",\3;' data
```

Or if your `sed` support the loading of `ERE`, such as `GNU sed`, you can avoid all the escaping job:

```
  sed -E 's;([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|(.+)$;\1,"\2",\3;' data
```

---

You can exploit the fact that only the middle group is delitmited by a `|` at each boundaries and make `sed` even more shorter:

```
sed 's;|\([^|]*\)|;,"\1",;' data
```

Of course also here, if your sed support `-E` you can load the `ERE` and avoid a tedious escaping job

Answer (score 0):

SImilar idea to @Kusalananda's: use a specialized CSV parsing tool. This is a ruby example:

```bsh
ruby -rcsv -e 'CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift, col_sep: "|") {|row| puts CSV.generate_line row}' file
```

```
1,"a,b",4
1,"c,d",4
1,"e,f",4
1,"g,h",4
1,"i,j",4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F "|" 'OFS="|" {print $1,"\""$2"\"",$3}' filename
```

output

```
1|"a,b"|4
1|"c,d"|4
1|"e,f"|4
1|"g,h"|4
1|"i,j"|4
```